# Statistical Theory of Power Sampling (within R code)

Tags: statistical-power, mathematical-statistics

I am curious about the statistical theory behind `power.prop.test` in R. I have dived into the [code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/power.R) behind it and detailed it in Latex format. My question here is:

1. What is the background of and the underlying statistical theory behind `power.prop.test`?

In a strict two-sided scenario
[image]

And in a non-strict one or two-sided scenario

[image]

Where…

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

n = current sample size

[image]